# Cleaning up this string of sed commands

Tags: regex, awk, sed

Ok, so my ultimate goal here is to produce a CSV file containing a list of AD groups and their members. I'm pulling the raw data with an `ldapsearch` command and requesting "dn" and "member" attributes for each group matching the pattern. Resulting data looks like this:

```
dn: CN=BLAH_GROUP1,OU=blah,OU=blah,dc=com
member: CN=John Smith,OU=blah,OU=blah,dc=com
member: CN=Dave Smith,OU=blah,OU=blah,dc=com

dn: CN=BLAH_GROUP2,OU=blah,OU=blah,dc=com
member: CN=Mike Smith,OU=blah,OU=blah,dc=com
member: CN=Chad Smith,OU=blah,OU=blah,dc=com

dn: CN=BLAH_GROUP3,OU=blah,OU=blah,dc=com

dn: CN=BLAH_GROUP4,OU=blah,OU=blah,dc=com
member: CN=Diane Smith,OU=blah,OU=blah,dc=com
member: CN=Amy Smith,OU=blah,OU=blah,dc=com
member: CN=Rebecca Smith,OU=blah,OU=blah,dc=com
```

Some of the lines wrap and are indented, so I just ignore any lines beginning with a space.

End result I'm looking for:

```
BLAH_GROUP1,John Smith,Dave Smith
BLAH_GROUP2,Mike Smith,Chad Smith
BLAH_GROUP2
BLAH_GROUP4,Diane Smith,Amy Smith, Rebecca Smith
```

I got to my result, but only by piping the output through sed 3 times though, and I'm just thinking there's probably a cleaner way to get there:

Current solution:

```
ldapsearch blah |                       # Generate data
sed -n '/^[^ ]/s/,.*//p' |              # Remove the wrapped lines and OU lists
sed ':x;/^dn{N;s/\nmember CN=/,/;bx}' | # Replace "member CN=" with "," and add to prev line
sed 's/dn: CN=//'                       # Remove "dn: CN="
```

I've tried just running these with multiple instances of -e, but it doesn't give the same results.

Comment: @oguzismail I like your solution, but it seems to assume a fixed number of members per group, whereas mine are varied. (Sorry, I know the sample groups each have 2 members.)

Comment: @oguzismail Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk and a regex as field separator:

```
awk '{
       if($1=="dn")     {a=$3}
       if($1=="member") {a=a "," $3}
       if($0=="")       {print a}
     }
     END{ print a }' FS='(: |=|,)' file
```

Output:

```
BLAH_GROUP1,John Smith,Dave Smith
BLAH_GROUP2,Mike Smith,Chad Smith
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: I like this awk solution a lot better than mine. Much more readable. I really, really need to learn awk.

Answer (score 2):

a rewrite of @Cyrus's solution

```
$ awk -F'[=,]'  '/^dn: /     {a=$2} 
                 /^member: / {a=a "," $2} 
                 !NF         {print a} 
                 END         {print a}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^dn: CN=([^,]*).*/{s//\1/;:a;N;s/\nmember: CN=([^,]*).*/,\1/;ta;P};d' file
```

On encountering a line beginning `dn: CN=` extract the next field, delimited by `,` and then append subsequent lines, denoted by `member: CN` and extract their next field too. If a further match does not occur, print the constructed line and delete anything remaining.

The same command without `-E` option:

```
 sed '/^dn: CN=\([^,]*\).*/{s//\1/;:a;N;s/\nmember: CN=\([^,]*\).*/,\1/;ta;P};d' file
```

Comment: Hmm, seems like I'm running GNU sed 4.1.5 on SLES, but I don't have the -E option. I tried -nr instead, but the output is missing a lot of members.

Comment: @MichaelDavis: I suggest to replace `-E` only with `-r` or `--regexp-extended`.

Comment: @Cyrus That was my assumption, it gave the same results as -nr.

Comment: @MichaelDavis see edit. Sorry I confused you with the `-n` option, it is not needed and was added into the text of the solution by mistake.